# Is it possible to call Complex soap API from QTP web-service addin?

Tags: web-services, soap, qtp

Is it possible invoke the SOAP API which returns object  of some class or which takes the object of class as input parameter via QTP web-service addin?

Is there any way to call overloaded API via QTP web service addin?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by creating a batch file by using testrunning.bat.

which will exexcute your soapui scripts in command prompt.